# Can stddev_samp() function be used with windows functions?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to compute the moving average and moving standard deviation for the last 10 purchases for a customer.

```
 avg(price) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date rows between 10 preceding and current row) as avg_price_10_orders,
```

I know I can compute the average, but I read conflicted information regarding whether I can compute the standard deviation this way:

```
stddev_samp(price) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date rows between 10 preceding and current row) as sd_10_orders
```

I am on Amazon Redshift cluster, the AWS documentation indicates it's okay:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_STDDEV.html

However, Cloudera source says stddev_samp() is not allowed to be used with over() clause: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/impala_stddev.html

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: What has Cloudera to do with your question if you are using Redshift?

Comment: are you running cloudera impala or aws redshift?

Comment: @Jon Scott aws redshift - I guess that kind of answers my own question: the AWS documentation then?